# How to change the text from a toollbar menubutton item in tinymce 5?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I've recently migrated from tinymce 4 to tinymce 5 and I cannot figure out how to create a dropdown menu like button and change its text based on the current selection.

Basically, I'd like to have something like the default Font or title button.

Here is how I create a dropdown button that will wrap selected text with `<span lang='xx'` tag.

```
addLanguageBtn()
{
    let lngBtn = editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('languageBtn', {
      text: 'Language',

      fetch: (callback) => {
        let items: any = [
          {text: 'French', value: 'fr', type: 'menuitem'},
          {text: 'German', value: 'de', type: 'menuitem'},
          {text: 'Spanish', value: 'es', type: 'menuitem'},
        ];
        
        items.forEach(item => {

          item.onAction = () => {

            let currentNode = editor.selection.getNode();

            if (currentNode.tagName.toLocaleLowerCase() !== 'body')
            {
              currentNode.setAttribute('lang', item.value);
            }
            else
            {
              let textToWrap = editor.selection.getContent();
              let wrappedContent = `<span lang='${item.value}'>${textToWrap}</span>`;
              editor.selection.setContent(wrappedContent);
            }
          }

        });

        callback(items);

      },
```

In tinymce's main `setup` method, I'd like to change that button's text to be the selected language whenever the cursor is placed on a word that is within a `<span lang='xx'` tag

```
  setup(ed)
  {
      
    let lngButton = this.addLanguageBtn(ed);


    ed.on('NodeChange', function (ev) {
      if (!lngButton)//No button
      {
        return;
      }
      let lang = ev.element.getAttribute('lang');
      lngButton.text = lang; // <==== This does not work, value is modified but UI is not updated
```

**Note**

Here is a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/davidb001/pen/PoNEgzV)

**Edit**: I had a look at tinymce's source code, and from what I could see they use Alloy components to create their own font family and font weight buttons. I'm just looking for something 'simple'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is any direct way to achieve this, as there already exists an [issue](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/5966) with same requirements as you in the repository of the project.

This is the reply from one of the contributors on the project:

> There's no way to currently do this sorry, as the buttons that do
> allow this (eg fontselect) currently use an internal only API. We do
> want to expose this for others to use, however we haven't yet
> scheduled the work to do that, so I'm going to label this as a feature
> request.
>
> Note: If you're a commercial customer I'd recommend logging this
> feature request via our support channels, as it'll receive more
> attention/priority than GitHub feature requests.